# Summary table of unique value combinations in DataFrames.jl

Tags: dataframe, julia

I often want to find the unique combinations of some grouping variables in a data table.  With R + dplyr, my normal workflow is to combine `groupby(data, var1, var2, var3) %>% summarise`, which returns a new table with the columns `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, with one row for each unique combination of values found in `data`.

What's the idiomatic way to do this in DataFrames.jl?

Answer (score 7):

In DataFrames.jl, a DataFrame is a collection of rows.  So the right mental model here is to first select only the columns you care about, then get the unique rows from that table, as in

```
select(data, [:var1, :var2, :var3]) |> unique!
```

(Or if you hate the pipe/love extra parens:

```
unique!(select(data, [:var1, :var2, :var3]))
```

`unique!` is recommended here because `select` makes a copy of the underlying columns.  Alternatively, you could use a view or indexing, but these require `unique` (which does not mutate the underlying column vectors) so as not to corrupt the original data frame:

```
unique(data[!, [:var1, :var2, :var3]])
unique(view(data, :, [:var1, :var2, :var3]))
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can write:

```
keys(groupby(data, [:var1, :var2, :var3]))
```

to get a vector of unique grouping keys. Then you can collect them to a `DataFrame` if you want by writing:

```
groupby(data, [:var1, :var2, :var3]) |> keys |> DataFrame
```